# How to use value returned from method whose returning datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

This method returns userId if particular emailID exist in database.

```
public DataTable isEmailExist(string emailID)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConString"].ToString();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("validateEmail", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"p_emailid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailID;
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                con.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);

            }
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

This is my mvc method to reset password which will call method to insert new password to database

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ResetPassword(ResetPasswordModel reset)
{
    AjaxResponse ajaxResponse = new AjaxResponse()
    {
        StatusCode = "Error"
    };
    if (reset != null)
    {
        ajaxResponse.StatusCode = "OK";
        PasswordReset(reset);

    }
    else
    {
        ajaxResponse.Message = "Reset Password Failed";
    }

    return Json(ajaxResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This method is to send data to database

```
private ResetPasswordModel PasswordReset(ResetPasswordModel reset)
{
    reset.Password = Encrypt(reset.Password);
    reset.ConfirmPassword = Encrypt(reset.ConfirmPassword);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConString"].ToString();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Reset_Password", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"p_resetUserID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = isUserIdExist;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"p_newpassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reset.Password;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"p_confirmPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reset.ConfirmPassword;
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    con.Open();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return reset;
}
```

**1.  isEmailExist method returns a userID and I want to use that userID for PasswordReset method.

2. want to use userId as parameter to stored procedure method.

3.But isEmailExist method accepts an email parameter so how to use it in PasswordReset method.**

Comment: Does your `ResetPasswordModel` already have the email address, that you are looking for?

Comment: _"isEmailExist method returns a userID and I want to use that userID for PasswordReset method."_ ...ok. But it's unclear where you're stuck. What happened when you tried to run that method? Your post describes your requirement, but doesn't describe any kind of problem. We can't see why you're stuck with implementing it. What goes wrong? What part of the process don't you understand? You need to execute the method and get the result.

Comment: If it returns a datatable, then you need to find the value within the table (if it's a single value, it's likely to be in the first cell of the first row of the datatable (although since you didn't show the stored procedure code, we don't actually have any idea what it will really return).

Comment: No that is only the issue isEmailexist accepts a parameter emailId  and returns userID from database so how can I use isEmailExist in PasswordReset method which has no email parameter.

Comment: Normally you'd get the ID of the currently logged in user from the Session. When using asp.net this is usually through the User.Identity object which should be available in all controller methods.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are trying to obtain the `userId` value from DataTable after calling the function `isEmailExist(string emailID)`.

Once you have the `userID` you can use it in calling the stored procedure or any other stuff.

A possible answer:

```
String userId = "";
DataTable dt = isEmailExist("x@x.com");

if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
{
   userId = dt.Rows[0]["Id"];  // assuming Id is the column name
}
```